# Select values with latest date and group by an other column

Tags: mysql, sql

#### See My Table and query here (on sqlfiddle)

 Myquery is fetching exact results that I need but it takes long time when data is more than 1000 rows. I need to make it **Efficient**

```
Select `id`, `uid`, case when left_leg > right_leg then left_leg
else right_leg end as Max_leg,`date` from
(
SELECT * FROM network t2 where id in (select id from
(select id,uid,`date` from (SELECT * FROM network order by uid,
`date` desc) t4 group by uid) t3) and
(left_leg>=500 or right_leg>=500))t1
```

Want to pick data from network againt latest dates for each uid
Wanted to pick data where left_leg >=500 or right_leg >=500
Wanted to pick only bigger of two legs (left or right)

Whole query might have some problems but **Core issue** is with this code

```
SELECT * FROM network t2 where id in (select id from
(select id,uid,`date` from (SELECT * FROM network order by uid,
`date` desc) t4 group by uid) t3)
```

**I want to improve this query because it fetches esults so much slow when data grows.**

Comment: Can you post your explain with the real data?

Comment: See JOINs, and then see GREATEST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your description:

- first find the max date for each uid
- then find the associate ids
- filter on the leg values

Example:

```
SELECT id, uid, GREATEST(left_leg, right_leg) as max_leg
  FROM network
  WHERE (uid, `date`) IN (SELECT uid, MAX(`date`)
                            FROM network
                            GROUP BY uid)
    AND (left_leg > 500 or right_leg > 500)
```

Note that this means that if the latest date for a uid does not have some legs > 500, then the records won't show up in the result. If you want the latest records with legs > 500, the leg filter has to be moved in.

Answer (score 2):

Add an index on (uid,date):

```
ALTER TABLE network ADD INDEX uid_date( uid, date )
```

and try something like:

```
SELECT n.id, n.uid, greatest( n.right_leg, n.left_leg ) as max_leg, n.date
FROM
  ( SELECT uid,max(date) as latest FROM network
    WHERE right_leg>=500 OR left_leg >=500
    GROUP BY uid
  ) ng
JOIN network n ON n.uid = ng.uid AND n.date = ng.latest
```